# Illegal base64 character "a" using java.util.Base64 from within Scala

Tags: java, scala, base64, decoding

Suppose I have the following Base64 encoded String from a github API call to a file:

```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```

As far as I see, this encoding is correct and only contains the standard alphabet of characters for a Base64 encoding. If I decode this encoding [here](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Base64(%27A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D%27,true)&input=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), I get a correct translation. However, I tried various approaches to decode it programmatically and did not find a solution yet.

Let `contentEncoded` be the string containing the encoded file. I tried the following:

```scala
java.util.Base64.getDecoder.decode(contentEncoded)
java.util.Base64.getDecoder.decode(contentEncoded.getBytes)
java.util.Base64.getDecoder.decode(contentEncoded.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
java.util.Base64.getUrlDecoder.decode(contentEncoded))
java.util.Base64.getUrlDecoder.decode(contentEncoded.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
java.util.Base64.getMimeDecoder.decode(contentEncoded.replaceAll("\\n", "").replaceAll("\\r", ""))
```

However, all of them resulted in an error message: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character a`.

My question is: Am I not seeing something obvious? Are there some hidden control characters? Has anybody had similar issues and was able to fix them?

Comment: Can you produce a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), for example by providing the code you tried with the input as a hardcoded `String` variable? The encoded data seems fine and the methods you claim to call should mostly work. My guess is that your input is not what you think it is.

Comment: It seems `a` in this error message is the hex value of the offending character, which means it's U+000a, better known as `\n`. In other words: the last line should work, the others might fail. Indeed you need to *either* remove the `\n` in the source or just use `getMimeDecoder()`: that one works as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following snippet decodes the encoding correctly:

```scala
val decodedWithMime = java.util.Base64.getMimeDecoder.decode(contentEncoded)
val convertedByteArray = decodedWithMime.map(_.toChar).mkString
```

as pointed out by comments, the error message `Illegal Base64 character a` corresponds to the hex value for the newline character `\n`. Using the Mime Decoder it is possible to decode the string without removing the newline characters beforehand.

Comment: `byte[] decodedWithMime = ....` and `String convertedByteArray = new String(decodedWithMime` for the Java implementation and not Kotlin as described above

Answer (score 17):

Just remove line breaks and it should work.

```
contentEncoded.replace("\n", "")
```

Comment: Better to use `replaceAll("\\R", "")` in case the text file is saved on Windows, where linebreaks are `\r\n`.

Comment: To make it multiplatform - use replaceALL("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", "")

Comment: Best answer yet.